# This is my SQL query that is used to retrieve the sum of quantity where product has same id, I want to use it in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-to-linq-conversion

This is my SQL query that is used to retrieve the sum of quantity where
product has same id, I want to use it in LINQ.

```
select p.ProductId,s.TotalQuantity,p.Title from Products p
    join (SELECT ProductId, SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity
            FROM SalePerProduct s join Invoices i on s.InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId
            where i.IssueDate like '%2016%'
            GROUP BY s.ProductId) s
    on s.ProductId = p.ProductId;
```

I have Tried this LINQ query but it does not work fine, It sums up the quantity having same product id but i am unable to show product title using this, need some help.
Thank you in advance.

```
 var sales = from sale in db.SalePerProducts
                        join product in db.Products
                        on sale.ProductId equals product.ProductId
                        where sale.ProductId == product.ProductId
                        group sale by sale.ProductId into g
                        select new
                        {
                            ProductId = g.Key,
                            Sum = g.Sum(sale => sale.Quantity),
                        };
```

Comment: so you want to see how many of the same id products are there?just to make sure

Comment: I want to  sum up all the products having same id, and if their id is same then their title should also be same.
e.g. if i have two records: 
1- 15 chocolate 200 5 
2- 15 chocolate 200 10 
It should become 15 chocolate 15

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer, finally i am able to retrieve multiple products with same name and PRODUCT_ID as a single record ans also sums up the quantity, Thankyou all of you.
Please vote up if you find this useful

```
var sales = from sale in db.SalePerProducts
                        join product in db.Products
                        on sale.ProductId equals product.ProductId
                        join invoice in db.Invoices
                        on sale.InvoiceId equals invoice.InvoiceId
                        where sale.ProductId == product.ProductId &&
                                invoice.IssueDate.Date == date
                        group sale by new { sale.ProductId,product.Title } into g
                        select new
                        {
                            ProductId = g.Key.ProductId,
                            Product_Title = g.Key.Title,
                            Quantity_Sold = g.Sum(sale => sale.Quantity)
                        };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var sales = from sale in db.SalePerProducts
                    join product in db.Products
                    on sale.ProductId equals product.ProductId                       
                    group new {sale, product} by sale.ProductId into g
                    select new
                    {
                        ProductId = g.Key,
                        Title = g.FirstOrDefault().product.Title,
                        Sum = g.Sum(s => s.sale.Quantity),
                    };
```

I removed unnecessary where clause, you have in your version.

Comment: It is not unnecessary in my case because in where clause i am matching it to the issue date, well thanks for your feedback :)

Comment: sorry, my version was related to the linq query in your original question. I didn't notice the difference to the sql query.